# Segmentation Fault with Circular Buffer Implemenation

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, circular-buffer

I am implementing a circular buffer but I am getting a confusing segmentation fault when I am testing my implementation. The code seems to produce a segfault right after I call a function to print out the contents of the circular buffer structure. This confuses me since I would have expected a segfault I am writing or reading from the buffer, but instead it seems to give the error right after returning from my print_cbuf() function.

Here is my circular buffer implementation:

```
#ifndef __CBUF_H__
#define __CBUF_H__

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct
{
    char* buffer;       // buffer start
    char* write;        // write pointer in buffer
    char* read;         // read pointer in buffer
    size_t size;        // element size
    size_t curr_len;    // current lenth of circular buffer
    size_t max_len;     // maximum capacity of circular buffer
} cbuf_t;

/*
* new_circular_buffer()
* Initialize and returns a new circular buffer instance.
*/
cbuf_t* new_circular_buffer(size_t capacity, size_t size)
{
    cbuf_t* cbuf = (cbuf_t*) malloc(sizeof(cbuf_t));
    if (NULL == cbuf)
        return NULL;

    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(capacity * size);
    if (NULL == buffer)
    {
        free(cbuf);
        return NULL;
    }

    cbuf->buffer = buffer;
    cbuf->write = cbuf->buffer;
    cbuf->read = cbuf->buffer;
    cbuf->size = cbuf->size;
    cbuf->curr_len = 0;
    cbuf->max_len = capacity;

    return cbuf;
}

/*
* circular_buffer_free()
* Frees all memory the circular buffer has dynamically allocated.
*/
void circular_buffer_free(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    free(cbuf->buffer);
    free(cbuf);
}

/*
* empty()
* Returns True if the circular buffer is empty, False otherwise
*/
bool cbuf_empty(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    return (bool) (0 == cbuf->curr_len);
}

/* 
* full()
* Returns True if the circular buffer is full, False otherwise
*/
bool cbuf_full(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    return (bool) (cbuf->curr_len == cbuf->max_len);
}

/* 
* push()
* Pushes new data into the circular buffer. This will not overwrite data if buffer is full.
*/
bool cbuf_push(cbuf_t* cbuf, void* item)
{
    if (cbuf_full(cbuf))
    {
        return false;
    }

    memcpy(cbuf->write, item, cbuf->size);
    cbuf->write = cbuf->write + cbuf->size;
    if (cbuf->write == cbuf->buffer + (cbuf->max_len - 1) * sizeof(item))
    {
        cbuf->write = cbuf->buffer;
    }
    cbuf->curr_len++;
    return true;
}

/*
* pop()
* Pop data at read pointer from the circular buffer and increments read pointer to next position
*/
void* cbuf_pop(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    if (cbuf_empty(cbuf)) 
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    void* item;
    memcpy(item, cbuf->read, cbuf->size);
    cbuf->read = cbuf->read + cbuf->size;
    if (cbuf->read == cbuf->buffer + (cbuf->max_len - 1) * sizeof(item))
    {
        cbuf->read = cbuf->buffer;
    }
    cbuf->curr_len--;

    return item;
}

/*
* size()
* Returns the current size of the circular buffer
*/
size_t cbuf_size(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    return cbuf->curr_len;
}

/*
* peek()
* Peeks the data at the read pointer without incrementing the read pointer.
*/
void* cbuf_peek(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    return cbuf->read;
}

/*
* reset()
* Resets all fields in the circular buffer instance and clears the buffer.
*/
void cbuf_reset(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    memset(cbuf->buffer, 0, cbuf->max_len * cbuf->size);
    cbuf->write = cbuf->buffer;
    cbuf->read = cbuf->buffer;
    cbuf->curr_len = 0;
}

#endif
```

And here is where I test out the implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "cbuf.h"

void test_circular_buffer(void);
void print_cbuf(cbuf_t* cbuf);


void test_circular_buffer(void) 
{
    printf("Starting circular buffer API tests...\n");

    cbuf_t* cbuf = new_circular_buffer(64, sizeof(char));
    if (cbuf == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not create circular buffer.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("=== Circular buffer created. ===\n");
    print_cbuf(cbuf); // SEG FAULT HERE ??
    // CODE AFTER THIS POINT DOES NOT EXECUTE ?

    // Empty Test
    printf("cbuf size: %d" , (int) cbuf->curr_len);
    if (cbuf_empty(cbuf) == true) {
        printf("Empty Test passed!");
    } else {
        printf("Empty Test failed!");
        return;
    }
    
    // Push 1 element
    char* data;
    *data = 13;
    assert(cbuf_push(cbuf, data));
    printf("=== Data pushed into circular buffer. ===\n");

    printf("SUCCESS! All test cases passed!\n");
    return;
}

void print_cbuf(cbuf_t* cbuf)
{
    printf("Circular Buffer:\n");
    printf("Buffer: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cbuf->max_len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, " , *(char *)(cbuf->buffer+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Buffer Start Address: %p\n" , cbuf->buffer);
    printf("Buffer Write Address: %p\n", cbuf->write);
    printf("Buffer Read Address: %p\n", cbuf->read);
    printf("Buffer Current Size: %d/%d\n", (int) cbuf->curr_len, (int) cbuf->max_len);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    test_circular_buffer();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Starting circular buffer API tests...
=== Circular buffer created. ===
Circular Buffer:
Buffer: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
Buffer Start Address: 0x149606750
Buffer Write Address: 0x149606750
Buffer Read Address: 0x149606750
Buffer Current Size: 0/64
zsh: segmentation fault  ./test_cbuf
```

If someone could shed some light on what is going on here as I am utterly confused and also give feedback on my circular buffer implementation that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Turn up the warnings and pay attention to them. https://godbolt.org/z/e7e7ffM9j

Comment: OT: Don't put function definitions (implementations) in header files. And all symbols beginning with double underscore (or a single underscore followed by an upper-case letter) are *reserved*, and you should never create such symbols in your own code.

Comment: In function ```new_circular_buffer```, what exactly ```cbuf->size = cbuf->size;``` does?

Comment: In write you use sizeof(item), you should use the size specified in your struct. * (char *)(buffer+i) can be written buffer[i] . You have some mistake like this in your code.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Typo: `cbuf->size = cbuf->size;` should be `cbuf->size = size;`

Comment: You need to initialize the elements of `buffer`, or `print_cbuf()` should not try to print the elements beyond the current size. You're printing uninitialized data.

Comment: What you've got going is more of a stack than a circular buffer.  A Circular buffer has  head and tail "pointers" and you usually get from tail and put at head.  If head == tail the buffer is empty.

Comment: cast `malloc()`. makes no difference for the compiler, but is good for you and your company and your people.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879184/11234199  your code has many problems. In special revise `push` since if the buffer is circular the `memcpy` will fail. Consider also the size of an item: if you do not allow a push to split item data the performance will be really bad as the buffer gets full

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you, with the help of the extra warnings I was able to track down the issues. Issue was incorrect pointer usage. Changing 
`char* data;
 *data = 13;
 assert(cbuf_push(cbuf, data));`
to 
`char data = 13;
 assert(cbuf_push(cbuf, &data));`
fixed my problem. For future reference, are there any good resources you recommend to learn more about compiler options. Currently lacking knowledge in this area.

Comment: To learn about compiler options: just read the documentation for your compiler and linker (which GCC runs automatically for you, for example).  ie, type `man gcc` and/or `man ld`.  Also, since we're discussing how to find memory mistakes, I want to recommend for you trying the tool 'valgrind'. If you run your program with valgrind, it may be able to detect and localize errors for you very quickly and completely automatically.